# python dict setdefault, confused

Tags: python

I was looking for an algorithm, and I can't figure out why the dict `d` has values in it and `curr` does not. I think it does not seem like anything is being done to dict `d`.

```
>>> def what(*words):
...     d = {}
...     print d
...     for word in words:
...     print 'word: ' + word
...         curr = d
...         for letter in word:
...             curr = curr.setdefault(letter, {})
...         curr = curr.setdefault('.', '.')
...     print d
...     print '?'
...     print curr
...     return 1
... 
>>> what('foo') 
{}
word: foo
{'f': {'o': {'o': {'.': '.'}}}}
?
.
1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault): it is like `get` but if the key wasn't present then it is also set:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> my_dict.setdefault('some key', 'a value')
'a value'
>>> my_dict
{'some key': 'a value'}
>>> my_dict.get('some key2', 'a value2')
'a value2'
>>> my_dict
{'some key': 'a value'}
```

Modifying a little your example:

```
>>> def what(*words):
...     d = dict()
...     for word in words:
...             curr = d
...             for letter in word:
...                     curr = curr.setdefault(letter, {})
...             curr = curr.setdefault('.', '.')
...             print 'curr is now: %r while d is %r' % (curr, d)
... 
>>> what('foo')
curr is now: '.' while d is {'f': {'o': {'o': {'.': '.'}}}}
```

As you can see `curr` changes, because when calling `setdefault` it sometimes(in your example always) create a new `dict` and set it as value to `curr`, while `d` always refers to the original `dict`. As you can see it **is** modified after the loop, since it's value is `{'f': {'o': {'o': {'.': '.'}}}}` which is quite different from `{}`.

Probably your confusion is due to the fact that `curr = curr.setdefault(letter, {})` **always** create a **new** and **empty** `dict`, which is then assigned to `curr`(and thus for every letter you add a nesting level to the original `dict` instead of overwriting the values).

See this:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> curr = my_dict
>>> for letter in 'foo':
...     print 'my_dict is now %r. curr is now %r' % (my_dict, curr)
...     curr = curr.setdefault(letter, {})
... 
my_dict is now {}. curr is now {}
my_dict is now {'f': {}}. curr is now {}
my_dict is now {'f': {'o': {}}}. curr is now {}
>>> my_dict
{'f': {'o': {'o': {}}}}
```

As you can see for every level the `my_dict` has a new nesting level.

Maybe, but I'm just guessing, you wanted to obtain something like `'foo' -> {'f': {}, 'o': {}}`, in which case you should do:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for letter in 'foo':
...     my_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
... 
>>> my_dict
{'o': {}, 'f': {}}
```

Comment: I get the setdefault part, my code is much different from yours.

Comment: @user584583 I strongly believe that simply reading the documentation carefully should solve your problem, anyway I've added an explanation regarding your example.

Answer (score 5):

`d = dict()` --> initializes an empty dictionary and binds it to the name `d`; so you have a dictionary object (`{}`) referenced by name `d`

**Inside the outer for loop**
`curr = d` --> binds another name `curr` to the same object. So, names (`d` and `curr` refer to the same object)

**Inside the inner for loop**
During the first iteration `letter = 'f'`

```
curr = curr.setdefault(letter, {})
```

There are 2 things that are happening in the above statement,

A) `curr.setdefault(letter, {})` --> As per documentation:

> "If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of  default and return default. default defaults to None.".

Since, the letter 'f' is not in the initial dictionary object it mutates the initial object to `{'f':{}}` and returns the value `{}`, which is not the initial dictionary object, but a new one that was created because of the setdefault statement. At this time both `curr` and `d` refer to the initial dictionary object which has since mutated to `{'f':{}}`.

B) Reassignment of the name `curr` to the return value mentioned above. Now, the names `curr` and `d` refer to different objects. `d` refers to the object `{'f':{}}`, while `curr` refers to an empty dictionary object, which is actually the value of `d['f']`.
This is why the nesting happens in the original dictionary object, as we go through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

### `setdefault(key[, default)`

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

> If `key` is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert `key` with a value of `default` and return `default`. `default` defaults to `None`.

**Usage examples**

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> d.setdefault('a') # returns the corresponding value for key 'a'
1
>>> d.setdefault('a', 10) # returns the corresponding value for key 'a'
1
>>> d.setdefault('b') # returns the corresponding value for key 'b'
2
>>> d.setdefault('c', 100) # returns the corresponding value for key 'c'
3
>>> type(d.setdefault('z')) # because 'z' is not a key of d, None is returned which is the default value of default 
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> d.setdefault('z', 666) # returns 666 since key 'z' is not in d
666
```

#### In your code

I think you are confused because `curr = curr.setdefault(letter, {})` always creates a new and *empty dict*, which is then assigned to `curr`. This means that instead of overwriting the values, you are adding a nesting level to the original dict for every element in `words`.

I also think that what you want to achieve with your code is to create a dictionary with every element in `words` as key with `{}` as value, so you can achieve it using the following code that uses a *dict-comprehension*:

```
def what(*words):
    return {word: {} for word in set(words)}
```

**Note:** I have added the explanation of `setdefault` since your questions has been viewed particularly for this case, but I wanted to cover your specific question too.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr `setdefault()` has a return value. (It returns the value of the key that was just inserted.) e.g.

```
>>> res = curr.setdefault(a_key, a_value)
>>> print(res)
a_value
```

I was also confused at first, thinking `setdefault` has no return value and thus

```
>>> res = curr.setdefault(a_key, a_value)
>>> print(res)
{a_key: a_value}  # incorrect
```