# Dictionary overwriting/erasing objects

Tags: python, dictionary, ip

Below is short form of my code of because the full code is too long.

Imagine somebody visiting your website and it gets your id *`steamid` in sample).  But my code only put's the last `steamid` in the dictionary.

```
def player_activate(ev)
  userid = ev["userid"]
  steamid = es.getplayersteamid(userid)
  data = {}
  data["Season 1"] = {}
  data["Season 1"][steamid] = {'points':20, 'kill':1}

print(data["Season 1"][steamid])
```

Only one steamid is shown in the dictionary and not all of them, so I get:

```
{'STEAM_5838512', 'points:20','kill:1'}
```

but what I want it to be is:

```
{'Season 1', 'STEAM_5838512', 'points:20','kill:1', 
 'Season 1', 'STEAM_83257231', 'points:20','kill:1'}
```

Comment: Are the last two lines supposed to be dictionaries? They're sets right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data["Season 1"] = {}
data["Season 1"][steamid] = {'points':20, 'kill':1}
```

You're setting the `Season 1`'s values in `data` to a blank dictionary, then afterwards, you're assigning that new dict a steamid.

Change it to something like the following, which uses [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
data.setdefault("Season 1", {})
data["Season 1"][steamid] = {'points':20, 'kill':1}
```

It checks to see if there's a key of  `data` called `Season 1`, and if there isn't, it sets the value of `data['Season 1]` to `{}`, which means that it won't override any existing data under `Season 1`.

Comment: Other than the official docs linked above, maybe this answer will  help http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555745/541208